# How to deserialize extra properties of json document into a map or other field with jackson?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I have a class/interface pair defined like this in Kotlin:

```
@JsonDeserialize(`as` = SimpleEvent::class)
interface Event {
    val organizationId: UUID
    val userId: UUID
    val eventTime: LocalDateTime
    val eventId: UUID
    @get:JsonAnyGetter
    @get:JsonAnySetter
    val details: Map<String, JsonNode>
}

data class SimpleEvent(
    override val organizationId: UUID,
    override val userId: UUID,
    override val eventTime: LocalDateTime,
    override val eventId: UUID,
    override val details: Map<String, JsonNode>
) : Event
```

My goal is to turn any extra fields from the json document as entries in the `details` map.  The `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations are promising, but I can't find a way to make `@JsonAnySetter` work with immutable constructor parameters.  `@JsonAnyGetter` works as intended, but `@JsonAndSetter` appears to be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me:

```
data class MyDataClass(
  val field1: Int,
  val field2: String,
  @JsonAnySetter
  @get:JsonAnyGetter
  val otherFields: Map<String, Any> = hashMapOf()
)
```

`@JsonAnySetter` tells Jackson to use the `otherFields` Map as a "catch all" for any name-value pairs it encounters during deserialization that can't be mapped to any of the explicit fields.

Conversely `@JsonAnyGetter` tells Jackson that `otherFields` is a source of other fields to be serialized, apart from the fields explicitly declared in the class.

I didn't get what the `get:` was for at first, but it turns out that it's a [use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) that tells the compiler to apply the `JsonAnyGetter` annotation to the Java getter generated from the Kotlin element (the constructor parameter). Without it the compiler complains that `@JsonAnyGetter` "cannot be applied to the target value parameter".

Answer (score 3):

As workaround, this works:

```
@JsonAnySetter
@get:JsonAnyGetter
        val others:Map<String,JsonNode> = LinkedHashMap()  /* workaround!*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonAnySetter` on a mutable property. It is not yet supported for constructor parameters, although there is a request to add that:

```
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/562
```