# how to convert C# code to Kotlin consist of Json library

Tags: c#, .net, json, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm kotlin newbie and have bad English sorry.

I want to convert to below code to Kotlin.

but I can't find a matching code with [JsonExtensiondata] in kotlin.

```
public class ProofAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("raw")]
    public string Raw { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ignore structural mapping of other properties
    /// </summary>
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> Rest { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jackson library for serialization/deserialization. If you choose to do so use the `@JsonAnyGetter` annotation which is described in the docs here:https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

> `@JsonAnyGetter`: annotation used to define a getter as "any getter", which returns a java.util.Map, contents of which will be serialized as additional properties for JSON Object, along with regular properties that the Object may have.

Check an example:

```
class Student {
   private Map<String, String> properties;
   public Student(){
      properties = new HashMap<>();
   }
   @JsonAnyGetter
   public Map<String, String> getProperties(){
      return properties;
   }
   public void add(String property, String value){
      properties.put(property, value);
   }
}
```

The `HashMap` is the equivalent of the dictionary with similar retrieval times and complexities.

Kotlin definition:

```
@get:JsonAnyGetter
val details: Map<String, JsonNode>
```

Comment: I have one more question. Idictionary<> is possible to convert to kotlin?

Comment: The Map is the equivalent interface.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750036/how-to-deserialize-extra-properties-of-json-document-into-a-map-or-other-field-w for a kotlin use example.